# EnableCors C# .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm working on a C# API and doing a GET request from my frontend and for that to happen I need to enable cors in my API, but I can't seem to do it!

It's a .NET Core 3 API and I've tried following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.0) tutorial and I've also tried installing the [2.2 NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors/) for it via:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors --version 2.2.0
```

But I still get a cors error when doing my GET request.

When trying the **[EnableCors]** annotation I get an error saying *"The EnableCorsAttribute could not be found"...*

I've also added

```
app.UseCors();
```

to my Startup.cs but with no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit - Startup.cs pasted here:** https://pastebin.com/pCLSh3Tf

**Edit - Controller pasted here:** https://pastebin.com/mUSfvNR0

Comment: Why the `mvc` package ? Is your api created using mvc or a normal .net core structure ? Can you try installing this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/

Comment: app.UseCors(
                options =>
                {
                    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:4021").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                }
            );

Comment: @HariHaran My bad. I wasn't using the mvc package. I've edited the question to the right package I used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsure if anything changed in Core 3.0, but in 2.2 I would solve it like this: add this to ConfigureServices

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
```

Also make sure you add your policy in the Configure method:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

You can edit the policy if you want to use cors, since this is basically disabling it.

Comment: I've added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors and copied your answer into my Startup.cs. Do However, when adding [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")] in the controller I still get "EnableCorsAttribute" could not be found. Any idea?

Comment: With this you can just remove [EnableCors] from your controllers.

Comment: For some reason I still get Cors errors and EnableCorsAttribute could not be found (I've tried removing it as well).. I've posted the Startup.cs if you would have a look: https://pastebin.com/pCLSh3Tf

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Startup seems fine, and it should be everything you need to configure CORS.

Comment: The Cors-"error"/message is from my frontend. The dev tools in Firefox tells me that "The cors request did not succeed", I've tried that with Java API's which is solved simply by allowing cors in the API. "The EnableCoursAttribute not found" is from my controller.

Comment: Also I think you should put app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); before app.UseHttpsRedirection(); , but I'm unsure if it will help.

Comment: By using app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); with the given policy, you are basically disabling CORS for your whole API.

Comment: I thought the current policy would allow requests from any origin, with any header and on any method?

Comment: Exactly. That's why i say it's basically disabling it. Put UseCors above UseHttpsRedirection(), and remove anything cors related thats not in startup from your API. Also try adding app.UseMvc(); at the botom.

Comment: Still getting the cors error.. Frustrating. But thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following at the beginning of ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors();
```

Add the following at the beginning of Configure:

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```